# I want to show Multiple Markers at runtime on the screen which have different id's that received from the server

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I want to show Multiple Markers at runtime on the screen which have different id's that received from the server and longitude and latitude also change or save on server.

**   Code work fine in 1 to 1 tracking but not work on multiple Id's PLEASE HELP ME..**

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
static final LatLng HAMBURG1 = new LatLng(74.3226214, 31.5003567);
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(74.3229122, 31.5003193);
private static MainActivity instance;

private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;
int i = 0;
protected static String longitudeServer;
protected static String latitudeServer;
protected static String uniqueidSserver;
protected static String latitudeLast;
protected static String logitudeLast;
protected static String uniqueidlast;
protected static double latilasdoublet;
protected static double longilastdouble;

double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener mListener;
private Marker marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()) {
            //  gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, 15);

            mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mLocationClient.connect();


            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Add menu handling code
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.mapTypeNone:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean initMap() {
    if (mMap == null && i == 0) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }
    return (mMap != null);
}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}


public void showCurrentLocation(MenuItem item) {
    Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    if (currentLocation == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(
                currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                currentLocation.getLongitude()
        );
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng, 10
        );
        mMap.animateCamera(update);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location : " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (i == 0) {
                gotoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 15);

                i = 1;

            }
           AppUtill.UniqueId();
            if (AppStatus.getInstance(getContext()).isOnline()) {
                new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://ip/hajjapi/api/GPSLocator/GetLocations");

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Turn On your WIFI ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            ///HOW I CAN DISPLAY MULTIPLE MARKERS WHICH HAVE DIFFERENT ID'S RECEIVED FROM THE SERVER PLEASE HELP ME PLEASE...

            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(new LatLng(latilasdoublet, longilastdouble)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4));
            marker = mMap.addMarker(options);

        }
    };
    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setInterval(5000);
    request.setFastestInterval(5000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, request, mListener);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void showcurrentLocation() {

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    i = 1;

}

class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    longitudeServer = obj.getString("longi");
                    latitudeServer = obj.getString("lati");
                    uniqueidSserver = obj.getString("uniqueid");
                }

                ////LAST LONGITUDE AND LATITUDE THAT RECEIVED FROM SERVER
                List<String> longitude = Arrays.asList(longitudeServer);
                logitudeLast = longitude.get(longitude.size() - 1);

                System.out.println(logitudeLast + " logitude ");


                List<String> latitude = Arrays.asList(latitudeServer);
                latitudeLast = latitude.get(latitude.size() - 1);

                System.out.println(latitudeLast + " latitude ");


                List<String> uniqueid = Arrays.asList(uniqueidSserver);
                uniqueidlast = uniqueid.get(uniqueid.size() - 1);

                System.out.println(uniqueidlast + " unique id ");
                latilasdoublet = Double.parseDouble(latitudeLast);
                longilastdouble = Double.parseDouble(logitudeLast);


                return true;

            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        if (result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}





 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    startService(new Intent(getContext(), Services.class));


}

public MainActivity() {
    instance = this;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return instance;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using only two double variables for lat and lng. create an arrayList of LatLng objects. for all the urls you get in response, add the LatLng to the arrayList.

1. add a field

   ```
   private ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList;
   ```
2. initialize in oncreate function

   ```
   latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. instead of

   ```
   latilasdoublet = Double.parseDouble(latitudeLast);
   longilastdouble = Double.parseDouble(logitudeLast);
   ```

   add

   ```
   for(int i=0; i< latitude.size(); i++){
      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(longitude.get(i)));
      latLngList.add(latLng);
   }
   ```
4. in place of

   ```
   MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(new LatLng(latilasdoublet, longilastdouble)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4));
       marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
   ```

   use

   ```
   ArrayList<MarkerOptions> list = new ArrayList<>();  
   for (LatLng object : latLngList){
       MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4));
       mMap.addMarker(options);
       list.add(options);   //if you want to keep track of all your markers
   }
   ```

use mMap.clear() to clear all markers and clustering refer

[More info on markers](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java).

Comment: Thanks rajeswari ratala
for(int i=0; i< latitude.size(); i++){
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i));
in this code      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i));
shows error

Comment: for(int i=0; i< latitude.size(); i++){
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i));
                    latLngList.add(latLng);
                }
Latitude.size shows error
latLng shows error
latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i)); shows error

Comment: the list is of strings. use Double.parseDouble. edited the answer. it should work

Comment: at com.example.muhammad.try1.MainActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:239)

when i do all your stuf

ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (LatLng object : latLngList) 
{ 
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4));
                    mMap.addMarker(options);
                    list.add(options); }
                
            Please Help me

Comment: for (LatLng object : latLngList) {
In this line point the error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference

error display when pointer plot on the screen

Comment: I didnt understand what  ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(); this is.
latLngList = new ArrayList<>(); add this in onCreate function. You will get nullpointer exception otherwise

Comment: please watch this new code on this link that i implemented i received null error..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354012/add-multiple-markers-android

Comment: latLngList is null

Comment: Thanks rajeswari ratala i resolve this issue 
I didnt understand what ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(); this is. latLngList = new ArrayList<>(); add this in onCreate function. You will get nullpointer exception otherwise 
this answer is verry helpful for me again thanks...